# C# - access Outlook address book in web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, outlook

I am developing a webapp in ASP.NET MVC C# where you can create automated emails that are sent out in the company yearly.

I am looking for a way to verify that the To-addresses specified by the user are valid and exist in the company.
I thought this could be accomplished by looking up Outlook's address book, since it contains all email addresses in the company.

I have searched around and found https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184631.aspx which suggests using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` package. However, as far as I can see, using this package requires that the Outlook application is installed. I suppose this can be problematic for a solution that runs on a server.

Can I use the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` package to accomplish my goal, or do I need to use another method that better supports a server?

Comment: Since your MVC app is likely running on a server without MS Office installed, this cannot work - look into querying your Active Directory where Exchange (and your Outlook address book) usually get their entries from.

Answer (score 0):

Following the tip of Filburt  in the comments, I found this code piece that accomplishes my goal

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/A-very-simple-example-to-8bbe95f0

It looks up in Active Directory.
I have simplified the code from the link to the following. In this example we check if the email address `addyToCheck@domain.com` exists in the AD:

```
using System.DirectoryServices;

// check if address exists
var searcher = new DirectorySearcher();
searcher.Filter = "(&(mail=" + "addyToCheck@domain.com" + "))";
if (searcher.FindOne() != null) {
    // the email exists in AD - all good!
}
```

This works for me locally and I suppose it will on the server as well. Let me know if you see anything wrong. Thank you.

Comment: How to get Distribute email list with the searcher? can u help me, please?